# How can I use Vaadin with SparkJava

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8, spark-java, vaadin10

I have implemented an API that is REST based using SparkJava (http://sparkjava.com). Its a standalone app and works great.

Now I'd like to implement part of that functionality access through a Vaadin UI. I'm quite new to Vaadin as well.

Does anyone know how I can still keep the single VM model, and able to use Vaadin's wonderful UI structures with greatness of SparkJava?

Is there someway that I can bind the Vaadin Servlet to the SparkJava Route perhaps?? Just thinking loud here.

Appreciate your help very much!!

I assume this is possible because I saw its used with Jetty ([Vaadin 10/11 and embedded Jetty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52420045/vaadin-10-11-and-embedded-jetty/54805756))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sure that is possible! You can simply make Jetty expose both SparkJava filter, and Vaadin 10+ servlet. I've created an example application which builds on Alejandro's work: https://github.com/mvysny/embedded-jetty-demo

Comment: Hi Martin, Now I'm trying to add Spark to the same solution. Would you know any answer to this at all:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54835994/apache-shiro-with-embedded-jetty-or-spark-java-is-it-possible?noredirect=1#comment96511629_54835994