# Apache Shiro with Embedded-Jetty or Spark-Java - Is it possible?

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty, shiro, spark-java

Does anyone have an example project on how I could integrate Shiro with Spark-Java/Jetty(embedded) please?

I can see from http://sparkjava.com/documentation#filters that it must be the way. But not sure what would be the smartest way to do this according to https://shiro.apache.org/web.html

If you may have any examples, appreciate much!

Comment: Have you tried adding Shiro via the servlet fragment?

Comment: HI @BrianDemers No I haven't (I think..).. can you explain your question a bit more please? Any code fragment by any chance?

Comment: Have you seen the samples in Shiro's repo? https://github.com/apache/shiro/tree/master/samples

Comment: yes. I need to do without the web.xml.

Comment: How about using a fragment? https://github.com/apache/shiro/tree/master/samples/servlet-plugin
Or just programmatically add the filter the same way?

Comment: I don’t have JSP at the moment. Started the project with SparkJava and Vaadin. Now moved to Jetty with SparkJava Filter and Vaadin. At the moment trying to get Shiro in a clean fashion. Configuration management is hand coded to keep super flexible, hence no web.xml.. instead pragmatic.. hope this gives a background..